# Date Difference between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following structure

```
RetailerCode   Orderdate
1001           01-JUL-16
1001           04-JUL-16
1001           06-JUL-16
```

I want this output

```
1001      10/9/2011 - 12/9/2011     2 days
1001      12/9/2011 - 20/9/2011     8 days
1001      20/9/2011                 NA
```

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a `RetailerCode` of 1001.  I'm guessing that's what the first row of your output is supposed to represent.  So how do you get from the sample data to the expected output?

Comment: Your example has data in july but result in september. Can you please edit the question to better explain your need?

Answer (score 1):

It s look like simple analitic functions

```
select RetailerCode, tO_char(Orderdate,'DD/mm/YYYY')||nvl2(next_Orderdate,' - '||tO_char(next_Orderdate,'DD/mm/YYYY'),'') Orderdate_diff, nvl(to_char(next_Orderdate - Orderdate),'NA') count_days from 
(select RetailerCode, Orderdate,  
                      lead(Orderdate) over (partition by RetailerCode order by Orderdate) next_Orderdate from YOUR_TABLE
 )
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I believe this will give an error

Comment: @Michael Piankov Thank u very much

Comment: @kumarh, let me tell you some basics about Stackoverflow. When someone is writing an answer and the answer works for you, please accept the answer ([See here for a description how to accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)). You have many questions where you commented the answer instead of accepting.